# form not showing up properly in chrome and IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Here is my page. I need to insert whole code here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tabs ul li:first a').addClass("active");
        $('#forms').find('form').hide().fadeIn(1500);
        $("#tabs ul li").click(function() {
            $("#tabs ul li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("#forms form").hide();
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
            $(activeTab).fadeIn();
            return false; 
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
body { background:#27476B; }
.clear { clear:both; }
#wrapper { width:510px; height:331px; overflow:hidden; padding:10px; }
#tabs ul { padding-left:15px; list-style:none; }
#tabs ul li { display:block; float:left; text-align:center; }
#tabs ul li a { padding:3px 20px 2px 20px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; border-top:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc; }
#tabs ul li a:hover { background:#AEBAC1; } 
#tabs ul li a.active, #tabs ul li.active a:hover { background:#AEBAC1; color:#333; }
#forms form { background:#AEBAC1; border:2px solid #333; padding-left:5px; }
.twocol { display:block; float:left; width:250px; margin-bottom:10px; }
.twocol label { margin-top:.33em; display:block; width:240px;}
.twocol select, .twocol input[type="text"] { background:#456A87; color:#fff; display:block; width:240px; font-size:16px; }
.twocol span { padding:0 8px 0 5px; }
.search { width:500px; text-align:center; margin-bottom:5px; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#properties">Properties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#developments">Developments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#agents">Agents</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="forms">
        <!--
                Search Form for Properties
        -->
          <form id="properties" name="properties" method="post" action="">
          <div class="twocol">
              <label for="city">City:</label>
              <select name="city" size="1">
                <option>-</option><option>asdfadf</option><option>-</option>
              </select>

              <label for="bedrooms">Bedroom:</label>
              <select name="bedrooms" size="1">
                <option>-</option>
              </select>

              <label for="minprice">Minimum Price:</label>
              <select name="minprice" size="1">
                <option>-</option>
              </select>

              <label for="minarea">Minimum Area:</label>
              <select name="minarea" size="1">
                <option>-</option>
              </select>

              <label for="propertytype">Property Type:</label>
              <select name="propertytype" size="1">
                <option>-</option>
              </select>

          </div>
          <div class="twocol">
              <label for="location">Location:</label>
              <select name="location" size="1">
                <option>-</option>
              </select>

              <label for="addedwithin">Added Within:</label>
              <select name="addedwithin" size="1">
                <option>-</option>
              </select>

              <label for="maxprice">Maximum Price:</label>
              <select name="maxprice" size="1">
                <option>-</option>
              </select>

              <label for="maxarea">Maximum Area:</label>
              <select name="maxarea" size="1">
                <option>-</option>
              </select>

              <label for="searchfor">Search For:</label>
              <input name="searchfor" type="radio" value="sale" /><span>Sale</span>
              <input name="searchfor" type="radio" value="purchase" /><span>Purchase</span>
              <input name="searchfor" type="radio" value="rental" /><span>Rental</span>
          </div>
          <hr class="clear" /><br />
          <div class="search">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
          </div>
          </form>
        <!--
                Search Form for Developments
        -->
        <form id="developments" name="developments" method="post" action="">
            <div class="twocol">
                <label for="city">City:</label>
                <select name="city" size="1">
                    <option>-</option><option>asdfadf</option><option>-</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="twocol">
                <label for="developmentname">Development name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="developementname" />
            </div>
            <hr class="clear" /><br />
            <div class="search">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the perfect view (on Firefox)
    [image: Firefox Snapshot]

Following problems are identified by me, Please let me know if there are some others too.

1. IE8 and Chrome are showing some extra height (which is displaying a little part of 2nd form)
   [image: IE8 Snapshot]
2. IE6 not showing the width specified in CSS.
3. In IE6, initially tabs div is touching with the forms div. But on mouse over it adds some extra spacing.
   [image: IE6 Snapshot]

How can it be solved.

Comment: Forget IE6 - http://www.bringdownie6.com/

Comment: @Calum: I have forgotten IE6, my client is not forgetting it. Because he has IE6 on his computer

Comment: I think your non-active forms need to have "display:none" for starters. That way they won't peek out, size or not. Also you need to clear floats inside your TABS div.

Comment: to be perfectly honest, I'm dead impressed you've managed to get IE6 looking as close as it does to the other browsers. Web developers should be charging at least 100% extra these days if IE6 compatibility is a requirement; that's a fair reflection on how much exta work it causes.

Comment: @Spudley: I need some help to solve this problem.

Comment: @Spudley: You are so, so right

Comment: @Spudley - I'm always happy to debug for IE6 - extra money is extra money + if the client is really an ass there is no problem to charge some extra fee for the nerves - they will understand since they want it to work.

Comment: @booota: Have you tried http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite/ (watch: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLJ2RaNZ22E)  or http://www.firebugger.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by points 1 & 2, but 3 I got it fixed. I might have fixed 1 & 2(not sure).

Let me know how this works for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/3uMyA/3/

Comment: @ Alex: thanks. I hope you added "display:inline-block" in "ul". Thats done. Now point 1 has been cleared. Now comes point 2 only. It says that the dropdown boxes used in the forms are stretched in newer version to 240px width. But that css for width is not working in IE6. What may the solution. Kindly, check the original and IE6 screenshots.

Comment: Add this separate, .twocol select { width: 240px; }

It might the be atribute selector messing with IE.

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/3uMyA/5/